# All Bootstrap rows are in one row

Tags: reactjs, rows

Here is one weird problem. I can't believe this happen. How?

```
<div className="dis">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio
            soluta non ut, aliquid molestias possimus? Pariatur commodi
            doloremque laborum, vel, sequi quaerat consectetur quas ratione
            nihil culpa nulla est nobis.
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio
            soluta non ut, aliquid molestias possimus? Pariatur commodi
            doloremque laborum, vel, sequi quaerat consectetur quas ratione
            nihil culpa nulla est nobis.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio
            soluta non ut, aliquid molestias possimus? Pariatur commodi
            doloremque laborum, vel, sequi quaerat consectetur quas ratione
            nihil culpa nulla est nobis.
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio
            soluta non ut, aliquid molestias possimus? Pariatur commodi
            doloremque laborum, vel, sequi quaerat consectetur quas ratione
            nihil culpa nulla est nobis.
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
</div>
```

This is happening. I have two rows, but both are in line with my website. This is the react.js project.
[image: This is happening. I have two rows, but both are in line with my website. This is the react.js project.]

Does anyone have some idea?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: can you share the style properties of class "dis"

Comment: Thank you for your response. Of course, I can, but there is the only background color.
```
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't spot the problem. Perhaps if you can share your files or preview, we can inspect the css and let you know.

In another way, take the whole section out of `<div className="dis">`. Apply your background colour on the container class style. See if that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your try, but nothing. I remove dis class but the same problem is here

Answer (score 0):

in React

```
<div className="dis">
 <Container>
  <Row>
    <Col md={6}>a</Col>
    <Col md={6}>b</Col>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Col md={6}>c</Col>
    <Col md={6}>d</Col>
  </Row>
 </Container>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your try, but it is the same. I installed react-bootstrap package, but nothing. I can believe it happen...